# Ckeditor load data with jquery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Iam having a bit of a trouble loading content to CKeditor from within Jquery.
I have a list of mail schemas, and for each of thoose i have a edit link, so the user should be able to edit the schema (in CKeditor).

My Jquery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $("#editor").ckeditor();
        $.get("test.php", function(data){
            $("#editor").val(data);
        });
        $(".editMailSchema").slideToggle("slow");   
  });
});
```

The html element looks like this:

```
<div class="editMailSchema">
    <textarea id="editor" name="editor"></textarea>
</div>
```

The element is being Toogled but without the content from test.php.
test.php looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "test";
?>
```

Could anyone please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by editing my jquery code like this:

```
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $("#mailSchema1").ckeditor();
        $.get("php/settings/test.php", function(data){
            $('#mailSchema1').val(data);
        });
        $(".editMailSchema").slideToggle("slow");   
  });
```

Now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

[Plugin](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery)

```
//for setting or getting the data of the Ckeditor use
// Get the editor data.
var data = $( 'textarea.editor' ).val();
// Set the editor data.
$( 'textarea.editor' ).val( 'my new content' );
```

Comment: Iam aware of that, thats why i have this in my code:

$("#editor").val(data);